# Include "Working Directory" pseudo-revision in revision history view

Tags: tortoisehg

If no revision set query is active in TortoiseHG, the revision history view includes a "★ Working Directory ★" pseudo revision showing the current changes on top of the last updated-to changeset.

When working in a branch I often show all changesets that are only under a specific bookmark by using the revision set query `only(bookmark)`. However in this case, the "★ Working Directory ★" pseudo revision isn't shown, requiring me to clear the current query every time I want to check the current changes. Is there a way to make TortoiseHG always show the "★ Working Directory ★" pseudo revision in the revision history view?

Any other recommendation to show the "revisions in a branch" plus the current changes would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the current changes, click the **Commit** button in the **Task Toolbar** [image] (the big green check symbol) or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Then click the **Revision Details** button or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to go back to revision history.

Reference: https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workbench.html#task-toolbar